# How to change the namespace in xml using xslt

Tags: .net, xml, xslt

I need to convert all my attributes in the xml to elements with some conditions. Say for example some attributes should be prefixed with the "Value" to it. I achieved this far. Along with this I need to change my namespace also. I couldn't achieve that.

**XML**

```
<Template xmlns="styling/1.0.0" Name="TemplateFromDictionary">

  <Style Name="Default">
    <Fill Color=""/>
    <Stroke Color="0000FF" LineStyle="Single" Width="1"/>
    <Symbol Color="FFFFFF" Name="default.png" ScaleX="100" ScaleY="100" ScaleMode="Drawing"/>
  </Style>

  <Style Name="Parcel">
    <Fill Color="48F5F5F5"/>
    <Stroke Color="C0C0C0" LineStyle="Single" Width="1"/>
    <Symbol Color="FFFFFF" Name="default.png" ScaleX="100" ScaleY="100" ScaleMode="Drawing"/>
  </Style>

</Template>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                xmlns:s="styling/1.0.0"
                xmlns="styling/1.0.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="s:Style|s:Template">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:variable name="name">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="name"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{$name}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@Color|@Width|@ScaleX|@ScaleY|@LeftIndent|@RightIndent|@FirstLineIndent|@SpaceBefore|@SpaceAfter|@Size" mode="name">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), 'Value')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*" mode="name">
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Template Name="TemplateFromDictionary" xmlns="styling/1.0.0">

  <Style Name="Default">
    <Fill>
      <ColorValue></ColorValue>
    </Fill>
    <Stroke>
      <ColorValue>0000FF</ColorValue>
      <LineStyle>Single</LineStyle>
      <WidthValue>1</WidthValue>
    </Stroke>
    <Symbol>
      <ColorValue>FFFFFF</ColorValue>
      <Name>default.png</Name>
      <ScaleXValue>100</ScaleXValue>
      <ScaleYValue>100</ScaleYValue>
      <ScaleMode>Drawing</ScaleMode>
    </Symbol>
  </Style>

  <Style Name="Parcel">
    <Fill>
      <ColorValue>48F5F5F5</ColorValue>
    </Fill>
    <Stroke>
      <ColorValue>C0C0C0</ColorValue>
      <LineStyle>Single</LineStyle>
      <WidthValue>1</WidthValue>
    </Stroke>
    <Symbol>
      <ColorValue>FFFFFF</ColorValue>
      <Name>default.png</Name>
      <ScaleXValue>100</ScaleXValue>
      <ScaleYValue>100</ScaleYValue>
      <ScaleMode>Drawing</ScaleMode>
    </Symbol>
  </Style>

</Template>
```

In output instead of this

```
<Template Name="TemplateFromDictionary" xmlns="styling/1.0.0">
```

I need this

```
<Template Name="TemplateFromDictionary" xmlns="styling/2.0.0">
```

I tried by changing the namespace in xslt to `xmlns="styling/2.0.0"` But this is giving the results like

`<Fill><ColorValue xmlns="styling/2.0.0"></ColorValue></Fill>`

The namespace is embedded into all elements and the Template element looks the same

`<Template Name="TemplateFromDictionary" xmlns="styling/1.0.0">`

I need the output exactly same as the output mentioned above only that namespace in Template element needs to be changed.

I am transforming this with C#.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the namespace of *all* elements you can reconstruct them with  `xsl:element` using a `namespace` attribute. So the following code changes two templates and adds a general "use-new-namespace" template:

```
<!-- use-new-namespace template for all s:* elements -->
<xsl:template match="s:*">   
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="styling/2.0.0">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>  

<!-- modified templates for new namespace -->
<xsl:template match="s:Style|s:Template">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="styling/2.0.0">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:variable name="name">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="name"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{$name}" namespace="styling/2.0.0">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

---

So the whole XSLT file is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                xmlns:s="styling/1.0.0"
                xmlns:t="styling/2.0.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- use-new-namespace template for s:* elements -->
  <xsl:template match="s:*">   
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="styling/2.0.0">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>  

  <!-- modified templates for new namespace -->
  <xsl:template match="s:Style|s:Template">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="styling/2.0.0">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:variable name="name">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="name"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{$name}" namespace="styling/2.0.0">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@Color|@Width|@ScaleX|@ScaleY|@LeftIndent|@RightIndent|@FirstLineIndent|@SpaceBefore|@SpaceAfter|@Size" mode="name">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), 'Value')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*" mode="name">
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am so sorry I couldn't understand. Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: In short, add the first template above and change the other two in your XSLT. Then every element will get the new namespace.

Comment: I have now one more problem in this. This is a new enhancement I need to do. Actually while writing the output for symbols `<Name>default.png</Name>` the name attribute has to be prefixed with C:\ or C:\dwg\ based on the content in the Name attribute contains 'png' or 'dwg'. I tried putting the condition in here inside this `<xsl:template match="@*">`. But I couldn't get this working. Could you please help me on this ?

Comment: @shansfk: I guess this qualifies as a whole new question. I can't tell from the comment what you expect to be changed...maybe a case for `xsl:choose`... A new questions with a good [mcve] will surely help with that.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve your goal is to rewrite the Template element with the new namespace. For example : add the following template to your xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="s:Style">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="s:Template" xmlns:ns2="styling/2.0.0">
  <ns2:Template>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </ns2:Template>
</xsl:template>
```

and remove the old s:Style|s:Template matching template

to be more clear:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                xmlns:s="styling/1.0.0"
                xmlns="styling/1.0.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
<!--    
  <xsl:template match="s:Style|s:Template">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
-->    
<xsl:template match="s:Style">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="s:Template" xmlns:ns2="styling/2.0.0">
  <ns2:Template>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </ns2:Template>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:variable name="name">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="name"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{$name}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@Color|@Width|@ScaleX|@ScaleY|@LeftIndent|@RightIndent|@FirstLineIndent|@SpaceBefore|@SpaceAfter|@Size" mode="name">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), 'Value')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*" mode="name">
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Don't you think OP might want the new namespace applied to _all_ elements, and the old namespace essentially discarded?